# How do you set the duration of an animate.css animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animate.css

I have read the documentation but am confused about how to actually write the code. The animate.css documentation instructs:

```
#yourElement {
  -vendor-animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

Note: be sure to replace "vendor" in the CSS with the applicable vendor prefixes (webkit, moz, etc)

First: Does this go in the style section, or can I use jquery to set and change the duration (ultimately I need to figure out how to do this, because the duration will be variable);

Second: how do I know what the 'applicable vendor prefixes' are? The animation I am using is 'pulse' from [this](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) site.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in your CSS, or you can set it dynamically. To find out the vendor prefixes you need, look on [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com) for CSS animations and see which browsers you want to support.

However, if your animations are complex, you may want to use JavaScript animation, which will give you more control. JS animation isn't slower than CSS animation, it's jQuery that's slow for animation. A good and performant JavaScript library for animation is **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)**.

Answer (score -1):

You can use these CSS properties.

```
transition-delay:3s;
transition-duration:3s;
```

Which you need you can use.
And Also Must Add -webkit, -moz and -ms for this.